# Why does the compiler not enforce the return type value for a generic that extends an interface?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    ClassB clazzB1 = getClassA(); // compile error
    ClassB clazzB2 = getInterfaceC1(); // compile error
    ClassB clazzB3 = getInterfaceC2(); // no compile error
  }
  
  public static <T extends ClassA> T getClassA() {
    return (T) new ClassA() {};
  }
  
  public static InterfaceC getInterfaceC1() {
    return new InterfaceC() {};
  }

  public static <T extends InterfaceC> T getInterfaceC2() {
    return (T) new InterfaceC() {};
  }

  private static abstract class ClassA {
    
  }
  
  private static class ClassB {
    
  }
}
```

```
public interface InterfaceC {
}
```

Why does getInterfaceC2() not give a compile error when assigned to clazzB3? It seems like it should and is something that I would like to have happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do:

```
static class InterestingType extends ClassB implements InterfaceC {

}
```

And then have :

```
public static <T extends InterfaceC> T getInterfaceC2() {
    return (T)new InterestingType();
}
```

As such calling:

```
ClassB clazzB3 = getInterfaceC2();
```

would work. In your case it is obvious to you that it will break, but the compiler can't prove that (easily). As such, your example is allowed, but will fail at runtime.

**EDIT**

The compiler looks at this:

```
ClassB clazzB1 = getClassA();
```

and sees that `getClassA()` returns a `T` that is defined as `T extends ClassA`, where `ClassA` *is a class*. It also sees that this `T` is assigned to `ClassB`, where `ClassB` *is a class also*. So it has to create a certain type that will conform to both `ClassA` and `ClassB`, something like a theoretical :

```
T extends ClassA & ClassB
```

but that is an impossible type, since no one can do `... extends ClassA, ClassB` (this is simply not allowed in java). So the compiler fails. As a matter of fact if you do :

```
javac  --debug=verboseResolution=all Test
```

you will see in the output, something like:

> error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible upper bounds ClassB,ClassA

On the other hand, when the compiler looks at this : `ClassB clazzB3 = getInterfaceC2();`, it sees that `getInterfaceC2()` returns:

```
T extends InterfaceC
```

and the result is assigned to `ClassB`, so it ends up with may be this type:

```
T extends ClassB & InterfaceC
```

which is perfectly valid. There *can* be such a type. I've shown you that you can create one as `InterestingType`, but as Holger pointed out, you could pass such a theoretical type yourself, via:

```
ClassB clazzB3 = Test.<InterestingType>getInterfaceC2();
```

this is called specifying a "type witness".

Comment: To much focus on the implementation side that is broken anyway and correctly gets a compiler warning for the `(T)` cast. Further, it's impractical to name the new class `Test` when the OP also has a class of the name. The important point is that the caller chooses the type arguments, so they can do `ClassB variable = Test.<TypeExtendingBandImplementingC>getInterfaceC2();` The validity of this construct does not depend on what the method does internally, that's how programming against an API works. And since Java 8, the validity can be inferred without the need to name the hypothetical type.

Comment: @Holger I perfectly understand that and this is how I initially wanted to answer, but the I saw "Student" under OPs profile, so decided that this would be easier... May be you are right

Comment: I should update my profile, I'm not a student anymore.

Comment: @Geoff even better; then you should most probably understand that Holger is referring to is "Generalized Target-Type Inference" that came out since java-8. You also understand why a compiler allows that.

Comment: I don't understand why `getClassA()` results in a compile error while `getInterfaceC2()` does not.